# Maximum and Minimum Value on Disk (No Lagrange)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, alternative-proof

Find the maximum and minimum values of $f(x,y)=5x^2+6y^2$ on the disk $D: x^2+y^2≤1.$

How would I do this question without using Lagrange?

EDIT: How would I do this using x= cos x and y = sinx then inputting them into my equation to solve for theta?
EDIT: I get up to $-10(cos(theta)sin(theta) +12(cos(theta)sin(theta)$ = 0

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: You can't just use $x = \cos \theta$ and $y=\sin \theta$... That way you just mov on the boundary. You must use $x =r \cos \theta$ and $y=r \sin \theta$, with $0 \leq r \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$. But it is pointless to do  this.

Comment: @PierreCarre It suffices to argue that no maximum exists on the interior and to *then* consider the boundary

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sure, but that argument must be made.

Answer (score 1):

$$0\le x^2+y^2 \le 1$$
$$\therefore 0\le 5x^2+5y^2 \le 5$$
$$\therefore 0+y^2 \le 5x^2+6y^2 \le 5+y^2 $$
$$\therefore 0 \le 0+y^2 \le 5x^2 +6y^2 \le 5+y^2 \le 6 $$
$$\therefore 0\le f(x,y) \le 6 $$

Comment: I thought you had to use x= acosx y =asinx (then plug in those values) into the equation and find the derivative and solve for theta?

Comment: Yes you can use that also let $x=aCos\theta $ and $y=aSin\theta $. Where $0\le a \le 1$  .  Therefore $ f(x,y)=5a^×+a^2Sin^2\theta $

Comment: Why does the answer become that? when I solve for those I get -10(cos(theta)sin(theta) + 12 (cos(theta)sin(theta) = 0

Comment: This is a nice elementary way (without trig or calculus) to obtain lower and upper bounds, but to complete the answer you must show that the bounds can be attained: $f(0,0)=0$ and $f(0,1)=6$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $5x^2+6y^2=5(x^2+y^2)+y^2$.

Comment: Question edited how would I do this question using x = cosx and y = sinx

Comment: @OGK it even simplifies the problem. Rewrite the problem in the new terms - what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The polar parametrization of the disk $x^2+y^2\le1$ is $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, with $r\le 1$. Then,

$$f(x,y)=g(r,\theta)=r^2(5\cos^2\theta+6\sin^2\theta)=r^2(5+\sin^2\theta)$$

For a given $r$, $g_{\theta}’(r,\theta)=0$ leads to $\sin2\theta=0$. It is straightforward to find that the minimum is
$g(r, 0)=g(r, \pi)=5r^2$ and maximum is $g(r,\frac\pi2)=g(r, \frac{3\pi}2)=6r^2$.

Then, taking $r\in[0,1]$ into account to get the overall minimum $g(0,\theta)=0$ and the overall maximum $g(1,\frac\pi2)=g(1, \frac{3\pi}2)=6$.